# Linking Errors after adding AudioKit via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, audiokit

I've developed a simple app that displays the live audio signal in a graph.
I installed AudioKit via CocoaPods with

> source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
> platform :ios, '13.4' 
> pod 'AudioKit', '=5.0.b1'

Everything works perfectly fine and now I want to integrate this functionality into an other App. 
This is where my problem begins. As soon as I ad the AudioKit pod to my other project I get linking errors. I'm not even using AudioKit in my code yet. I just edit my Podfile and use `pod update`.

This is what I get:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "_swiftoverride_class_getSuperclass(swift::TargetMetadataswift::InProcess const*)", referenced from:
> swift::swift50override_conformsToProtocol(swift::TargetMetadataswift::InProcess const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptorswift::InProcess const*, swift::TargetWitnessTableswift::InProcess const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadataswift::InProcess const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptorswift::InProcess const*)) in libswiftCompatibility50.a(ProtocolConformance.cpp.o)
> "swift::swift51override_conformsToSwiftProtocol(swift::TargetMetadataswift::InProcess const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptorswift::InProcess const*, llvm::StringRef, swift::TargetProtocolConformanceDescriptorswift::InProcess const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadataswift::InProcess const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptorswift::InProcess const*, llvm::StringRef))", referenced from:
> _Swift50Overrides in libswiftCompatibility50.a(Overrides.cpp.o)
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

After removing AudioKit from my Podfile and updating, everything is working again.

 The only other pod I use is [this](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) SideMenu.

My specs:
MacBook Pro 13 (2019, Big Sur 11.1, i5 1.4 GHz)
Xcode 12.3 (12C33)
CocoaPods 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try to switch to version 5.0.b2 instead of b1 - it was updated more recently and it's possible the old binary is having issues with Xcode 12.

Also you should upgrade to the latest CocoaPods - version 1.10 or later is required for proper XCFramework support, which is what the AudioKit pod uses.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm kinda embarrassed that the solution is that simple. Is there an easy way to keep track of new updates on CocoaPods or the Pods itself?

Comment: Do `pod update` every once in a while to get newer versions of pods, and typically the pod command should tell you if there's a newer version available.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Build Phases tab in the target settings.
If you see a run-script phase with a script that removes architectures from your frameworks (which is very common), Make sure it runs BEFORE the "Embed Pods Framework" build phase.

In addition, enclose the script code with

```
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]]; then
 [Original script]
fi
```